# Fixed width columns with displaystyle entries in an array

Tags: arrays

I cannot figure out why I get error messages like `! Missing $ inserted`. I would appreciate your help with this situation.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{r@{\ } >{\displaystyle}m{2cm} r@{\ } >{\displaystyle}m{2cm}}
1. & {{1}\over{50}}     & 2.  & {{22}\over{25}}         \\
5. & {{60}\over{24}}    & 6.  & {{49}\over{140}}        \\
9. & {{30}\over{125}}   & 10. & {{102}\over{150}}                   
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use `\over` but if you do, then you don't need any of the braces, `& 1 \over 50   &` but instead use `& \frac{1}{50} &`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be in math mode so

```
>{$\displaystyle}m{2cm}<{$}
```

But never use `\over` in LaTeX`.